# How to select datetime from the PostgreSQL?

Tags: datetime, postgresql

I want to to select the time of a date from database. How can I do this using postgresql database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date_part function, like this:

```
date_part('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

This would give you 20 for example.

For more information, refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly mean. Perhaps answer to your question is:

```
select now();
```

or maybe it's:

```
select now()::time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
select to_char (field, 'HH24:MI:SS') FROM table;
```

Example:

```
select to_char ('2011-04-13 11:22:33'::timestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

It gives you:

```
11:22:33
```

Replace